# skip radio buttons when posting the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http, radio-button, rack

I have a rails from inside that I have some radio buttons which I don't want to post in my Edit action.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/feedbacks/3" id="edit_feedback_3" method="post">
 <input id="1_1" name="1" type="radio" value="1" />Yes
 <input id="1_1" name="1" type="radio" value="1" />No
 <input id="feedback_answers" name="feedback[answers]" size="30" type="text" />
 <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and these radio buttons are not bound to a model's attributes, How can I POST only the 'feedback_answers' to server.

All this is because I'm facing this issue with [radio buttons](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3030-rails-does-not-handle-typeerror-from-rack-on-malformed-query-strings)

I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to handle this is to disable the radio buttons with javascript on submit:

```
function disableButtons() {
  document.getElementById('1_1').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  return true;
}
```

Then add the following in the form:

```
onsubmit="return disableButtons()"
```

Comment: if the answer was helpful to you, please share some love and upvote me. we don't all have 3k rep :)

Comment: hi I accepted your answer and then only put a comment. I appreciate you help, but adding points will take some time :D